# How to tell if a .so is for android and for the right arm version?

Tags: android, linux, architecture, shared-libraries, abi

I have a .so that I want to confirm as being from android or not, and for which arm version it is. Like: is it for armv7-a? armv8? x86 android or x86 linux?

I'm on Linux but a macOS command would also be great. Maybe one that works on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both GNU/Linux and macOS you can use `file`:

```
$ file */libtest.so                                                                                                                                              
arm64-v8a/libtest.so:   ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e6d1f9085a87057035b5ad7b0b1e3b66a4d7fecf, with debug_info, not stripped
armeabi-v7a/libtest.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=ba43c719e2ed6988e753f80163f4fca3f309d4ab, with debug_info, not stripped
x86/libtest.so:         ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=615ccead713c8b8a9155a229f9d530c1126c984b, with debug_info, not stripped
x86_64/libtest.so:      ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=390e1469af1f53ae3456f8a0464180d2bf3f6d18, with debug_info, not stripped
```

It's trickier to differentiate between Android and Linux since Android is Linux based, and runs Linux binaries and libraries.

Comment: I had used a tool that I dont remember and it said it was `aarch64`. The phone for which I was trying to compile the app was Mi 9 (snapdragon 855) which is armv8, however it was trying to compile and pick the armv7a version. Do you have any idea why?